# Using Bindevent in VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am currently facing an issue with event handling in Thinfinity.VirtualUI and would greatly appreciate any guidance and expertise.

I have integrated Thinfinity.VirtualUI into my application, and I am using the UploadFile method to upload files. Upon completion of the upload, an event named "OnUploadEnd" is supposed to be triggered, providing me with the name of the uploaded file. I would like to capture this event and execute a VFP program or method called "OnUploadEnd_EventHandler" that accepts the file name as a parameter.

To handle this event, I have attempted to use the BINDEVENT function as follows:

```
VirtualUI = CREATEOBJECT('Thinfinity.VirtualUI')

BINDEVENT(VirtualUI, "OnUploadEnd", loEventHandler, "OnUploadEnd_EventHandler")
VirtualUI.UploadFile(gTempdir)
```

However, despite the successful upload of the file, the event is not being captured and the "OnUploadEnd_EventHandler" method is not executed. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in identifying the issue and providing guidance on the correct approach to handle the "OnUploadEnd" event in Thinfinity.VirtualUI.

In my pursuit to resolve this issue, I came across the following blog post, which describes a similar scenario and provides some background information on the topic: https://blog.cybelesoft.com/upload-remote-files-web-enabled-applications. This is a fantastic product but the technical help files are sparse.

Thank you in advance for your valuable support. I eagerly await your response.

I have tried using Bidevent in various different ways but have been unsuccessful.

I have been given the following
can try this function:

UploadFileEx(const ServerDirectory: WideString; out FileName: WideString): WordBool;
Once the UploadFile ends it will trigger the following event:
OnUploadEnd(const FileName: WideString)

I do not however know the filename on the PC the user wishes to upload.

Comment: COM implements events differently than VFP. In COM you can bind only to an entire interface, which means you must provide ALL methods for that interface in a separate object called the event handler.

Answer (score 3):

To capture Com objects events you should use a eventhandler.

Use the the object browser to create the evenhandler class:

- open Thinfinity com library in the object browser
- locate the interfaces section; if there's more than one interface,  locate the one that has the onuploadEnd in the methods section
- drag and drop the interface to an empty prg and you'll get the eventhandler class named as  'myclass'
- write the desired code under onUploadEnd()

then do:

```
VirtualUI = CREATEOBJECT('Thinfinity.VirtualUI')
vuiEventHandler = CREATEOBJECT('myclass')
eventhandler(virtualUi,vuiEventHandler)
```

Look for EVENTHANDLER in vfp help.

Comment: Just one addition: The computer that builds the EXE must have the Thinfinity.VirtualUI object installed. Alternatively, you can specify a type library (TLB) file in the code. In either case, you must run VFP as Administrator in order to build the project, because VFP attempts to register the event handler in the registry.

Comment: Hi @ChristofWollenhaupt , Thank you for this. This is so helpful, I am testing it now.

Comment: @ChristofWollenhaupt, with the build project as an admin - is this a one off or will all future builds required this? What about the app at the customer site, will this also require admin rights?

Comment: Thank you so much @ChristofWollenhaupt. This has Worked!!! I have also answered he other 2 questions, yes it does need admin rights for every build and no the app does not at the customer site.

Comment: To build your project w/o admin rights just remove the OLEPUBLIC declaration from the class Vfp generates ( the eventhandler does not need to be a com object )